# Difference between DC operating point and Transient operating point

Tags: dc, transient

I've been simulating a circuit using synopsys and I'm just wondering what's the difference between DC operating point and Transient operating point?

[image]

Comment: I would guess that one set of values comes from a dc analysis and one from a transient analysis.

Comment: I don't know that there's any such thing as "transient operating point".  The DC operating point is the DC steady state equilibrium value for the node voltages and branch currents, but a transient is by definition a time varying response so where would a transient operating point make sense?

Comment: @JohnD see the figure above, there is that transient operating point in the simulator.

Comment: @djambalong OK, I think it's clearer now.  The transient operating point is the set of node voltages that exist prior to running a transient analysis.  That's usually the same as the DC operating point, but you might want to start the analysis with a different set of initial conditions.  Looks like the simulator allows you to do that.

Answer (score 1):

SPICE transient analysis uses different analysis algorithms with different convergence-related issues and different initialization parameters than DC analysis. But, a transient analysis first performs a DC operating point analysis.

Some circuits, such as oscillators or circuits with feedback, do not have stable operating point solutions. To simulate these circuits, the software either breaks the feedback loop so the DC operating point can be calculated or the initial conditions must be provided in the simulation input through .IC (initial conditions). The DC operating point analysis can be bypassed with various settings.

Once the bias is determined, the software  calculates the small signal circuit nodal voltages and currents, if these small signal values grow too large (or too far away from the initial DC operating point) the a new operating point is computed, a new set of small signal equations are computed around the new operating point and the process is repeated.

The series of operating points that are calculated are the transient operating points.

You can dump these and reuse them as initial conditions on the next run if you wish.